# Is there a way to convert an already made Blueprint to be the child class of another BP in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Basically, I have two blueprints already made. I made the parent first and then one that is supposed to be a child class of the first. However, being a beginner in Unreal I forgot to do it when creating the second BP. Is there a way to convert it to a child BP class after it has already been created?

For a use case, I have a Animal BP and a Dog BP and Dog should inherit from the Animal BP but, I didn't right click the Animal BP and create a child class when initially creating the Dog BP. Without destroying the Dog BP and recreating it, is there a way to convert it so that it inherits from the Animal BP?

Comment: You could add a Child Component to your blueprint and specify the second BP. You could also literally attach it (for example a gun attached to a player).

Comment: @Katianie Sorry, I guess I should have been a little more specific. I need the second BP to be a Child Blueprint Class of the first, not a child component wise.

Comment: I think you can inherit from a blueprint class which in turn inherits from that class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems I found it. If you open up the class BP, go to Class Settings -> Parent Class and select the BP you want to inherit from. I was looking through Class Defaults, no wonder I couldn't find it haha